# LINQ Modelling Column Name Same As Table Name

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there any way to name a column when LINQ modelling the same as the table?  Such as this:

```
[Table(Name="tblCC_Business")]
public class Business
{
  [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=false)]
  public string BusinessID { get; set; }

  [Column] public string Business { get; set; }
}
```

Our SQL table names don't necessarily reflect our business model naming scheme (it's a very large system which is why we do this).  I've known of techniques such as using underscores and @ symbols, although I wasn't sure if this worked for things like this.  It's more of a language thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[Column(Name = 'Business')] public string BusinessCol { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is what I previously did, I was just wondering if there was an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a member with the same name as its enclosing type in C#.